# asynchronously xml load and paged display in html

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, xslt

I'm in (great) need of some (cross-browser) asynchronously xml load, transform and paged display it by some .xsl stylesheet through an .html page.

More precisely, what I need is that prev next last first html links functionality work !
I managed creating the following:

1. persons.xml

   `<persons>
     <person> 
     <surname>Smith</surname>
     <name>John</name>
     <age>44</age>
     <address>1 Fiction Street</address>
     <city>SouthLand</city>
    </person>
    <person>
     <surname>Hardcastle</surname>
     <name>Belinda</name>
     <age>37</age>
     <address>3rd. Rose Road</address>
     <city>DownTown</city> 
    </person>
    <person>
     <surname>Elliot</surname>
     <name>George</name>
     <age>40</age>
     <address>21 Know Avenue</address>
     <city>Brownville</city>
    </person>
    <person>
     <surname>Jahore</surname>
     <name>Janice</name>
     <age>29</age>
     <address>14 Dragon Terrace</address>
     <city>Imagnry Town</city>
    </person>
    <person>
     <surname>Johnson</surname>
     <name>Tracey</name>
     <age>32</age>
     <address>11 Home Street</address>
     <city>Flowerville</city>
    </person>
    <person>
     <surname>Jalopy</surname>
     <name>Janus</name>
     <age>39</age>
     <address>63 Long Road</address>
     <city>Bigtown</city>
    </person>
    <person>
     <surname>Arthur</surname>
     <name>Bertrand</name>
     <age>45</age>
     <address>23 Sunrise Blvrd.</address>
     <city>MoonTown</city>
    </person>
    <person>
     <surname>Robert</surname>
     <name>Adolphe</name>
     <age>28</age>
     <address>32 East Lane</address>
     <city>Uptown</city>
    </person>
    <person>
     <surname>Eileen</surname>
     <name>Steward</name>
     <age>52</age>
     <address>12 Downsouth Blvrd.</address>
     <city>Albertville</city>
    </person>
    <person>
     <surname>Elizabeth</surname>
     <name>Parker</name>
     <age>62</age>
     <address>21 Jump Street</address>
     <city>San Thomas</city>
    </person>
    <person>
     <surname>Don</surname>
     <name>Stevens</name>
     <age>54</age>
     <address>10th Evergreen Terrace</address>
     <city>EastBourne City</city>
    </person>
   </persons>`
2. paged display stylesheet

```
     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:variable name="groupSize" select="3"/>
     <xsl:variable name="totRcrdNr" select="count(/persons/person)"/> 
     <xsl:param name="crrntPag" /> <!-- select="1" -->
      <xsl:template match="/persons">
      <html>
       <body>
        <h2 style="margin-left:67px">some persons listing</h2>    
        <table id="tbl" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:42%">
        <tr bgcolor="#b0d2b8"> 
          <th>Surname</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Age</th> <th>Address</th> 
           <th>City</th>
        </tr>
         <!-- select every first item in a group -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="person[position() mod $groupSize = 1]"/> 

        <tr class="tln"> 
         <td colspan="3">
         <xsl:if test="$groupSize * ($crrntPag - 1)&gt;$crrntPag"> 
         <span class="bpgn" style="margin-left:95px">  <!-- PREVIOUS and FIRST-->
         <a href="#" onclick=" ">&#171; </a>  <!-- << -->
         <a href="#" onclick=" ">&#8249; </a> <!-- < -->      
        </span>     
       </xsl:if> 
       </td>
      <td colspan="1">  
     <xsl:if test="$crrntPag * $groupSize &lt;=$totRcrdNr">
      <span class="bpgn" style="margin-left:16px">    <!-- NEXT and LAST-->
       <a href=" " onclick="init({$crrntPag + 1})">&#8250; </a> <!-- > -->
       <a href="#" onclick=" ">&#187; </a>  <!-- >> -->      
      </span>     
     </xsl:if>
     </td>   
     <td>pag: <xsl:value-of select="$crrntPag"/>/<xsl:value-of select="$totRcrdNr"/> </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     </body>
     </html>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:if test="position()=$crrntPag">
    <!-- list self and following siblings within this group -->
    <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::person[position() &lt; $groupSize]"> 
    <tr>  
    <xsl:for-each select="child::*/child::text()"> 
        <td> <xsl:value-of select="."/> </td>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </tr> 
    </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template> 
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

3. file.js - js script through which i asynchronously load and display that xml file along with those next prev links .html table border

```
 var xmlhttp = null, xslhttp = null, xmlRspn = null, xslRspn = null,
    xmlDetails = "xml/persn-en.xml",pass=0, pg,
    xslDetails = "xml/pgd_tbl_style-en.xsl", div_id = "tbl_show"; 

init(pg);

function init(pg)
 {
   pass++;  

  if(pass == 1) // that's somethng. temporary
    pg = 1

  sendRequest(xmlDetails, xslDetails,pg) 
}

function sendRequest(xmlURL, xslURL,pg)
 {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // first xmlHttpRequest for xml 
  if(xmlhttp)
  {
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange =  function()
                 {
                  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                  {  
                   xmlRspn = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                   doTrnsfrmGcko(div_id, xmlRspn, xslRspn,pg);
                  }
                 }    
   xmlhttp.open("get", xmlURL, true);
   xmlhttp.send("");
  }

  xslhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // second xmlHttpRequest for xsl
  if(xslhttp)
  {
   xslhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                 if(xslhttp.readyState == 4 && xslhttp.status == 200)
                 {
                  xslRspn = xslhttp.responseXML;          
                  doTrnsfrmGcko(div_id, xmlRspn, xslRspn,pg);
                 }
                }
   xslhttp.open("get", xslURL, true); 
   xslhttp.send("");
  }
 }

 function doTrnsfrmGcko(docElement, xmlDoc, xslDoc,pg) 
 {
  if(xmlDoc == null || xslDoc == null)
   return;
  else
  {
   var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
   xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslDoc);
   xsltProcessor.setParameter(null,"crrntPag", pg); // stylesheet parameter passing over
   var fragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc,document);
   document.getElementById(docElement).innerHTML = "";
   document.getElementById(docElement).appendChild(fragment);
  }
 }
```

4. index.html- very simple .html page where everything takes place.

```
  <html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/file.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body> 
   <!--<h3> List some people </h3> -->
   <div id="tbl_show"></div> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

Ok, now, if one will get all the files from here and put it to his/her own computer will quickly notice that either links ain't got no functionality whatsoever! 
 So please I need your support in making those links work!  first previous next last 
There is some fiddle like example for one to check what I mean about 
 next previous functionality:

```
        https://jsfiddle.net/MrcaS48/2e9kq3v0
```

See, through there the links are working !
Same thing I just need here to accomplish.

There were some small attempts in my code but are all wrong .. I think, mainly it's because there should be ajax calls for getting those links 
working.
 Again, you guys help me with this as I don't know how to do that

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Which browsers have you tested that with on your "own computer"? Chrome is known not to support XMLHttpRequest to local files, unless you lower its default security settings. And why on earth would you want to load the same file again and again for displaying fragments of it? The first load has the complete file, so store it. And the XSLT doesn't make much sense in the context of being called from Javascript to be inserted into an existing HTML document, if you want to insert the result of the XSLT into an existing `div` why would generate `html` and `body` elements with XSLT?

Comment: It's a working code over gecko brwsrs !
This bunch of files is correctly displaying what I need !
Wanted some way of async. xml (and xsl) load into a .html page.
If one'll closer check, one'll notice there are 2 ajax calls, ONE for each file.
When the code reaches that "doTrnsfrmGcko" function (which does that transfrm. & display) one has have loaded those two files (xml and that correspnd. xsl) in order for setup that transfrm. 
Two ajax calls !
Probl. here is I need that paginat. through those four links which ain't got no clue how to setup through some js/ajax!
That's the issue here!

Comment: Use Promises (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to load the two files asynchronously but to synchronize the transformation after you have the two files loaded. Although I am not even sure browsers bother to use asynchronous loading when loading from the file system. As for the code, you have some in there with `init({$crrntPag + 1})`, does that give an error? Which one exactly?

Comment: I would suggest to use `input type="button"` or `button` there instead of a link; for a Javascript link make sure you use `<a href="#" onclick="init({$crrntPag + 1}); return false;">...</a>`, otherwise the browser tries to follow the link and reloads the page.

Comment: @Martin Honnen   Yess! That was it:

     <a href="#" onclick="init({$crrntPag + 1}); return false;">...</a>

Needed to put "return false" in order for the browser not reloading that page again!
  Yes! Thank you very oh so much mr. Honnen. I appreciate it a great deal.
 The rest of functionality follows.
 And, you know, everything works out fine!!
                           Many thanks!!

Comment: I have morphed the suggestion from a comment into an answer so that you can accept it and the question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right call in there in one onclick handler (e.g. `init({$crrntPag + 1})`) but if you use a HTML link with `a href="#"` as a "button" to only call some Javascript code you need to make sure the link is not followed by using `return false` as the last statement in the onclick handler:

```
<a href="#" onclick="init({$crrntPag + 1}); return false;">...</a>
```

It would be easier to use a simple button with an `input type="button"` or `button` element instead of the `a` element.